# Athena Write to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

What are my options to programmatically run a SQL query on Athena and store the result set in DynamoDB as items or views.

I am looking for a built-in AWS Athena function/API which takes a Query as input and outputs the result set into DynamoDB.

Today [Athena API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html) can run given query and store the result set to S3. I am looking for Athena to DynamoDB API

Comment: what's the question exactly?

Comment: updated question with clarity

Comment: there's no such functionality afaik currently, you can have the query output to a certain bucket and create a Lambda trigger which monitors that bucket and loads it into DynamoDB that way for you, at least that is what i would do

Answer (score 4):

There is no built-in AWS functionality that allows you to get data from Athena to DynamoDB directly.

What you can do instead is to have [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) running Python script that uses [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to connect to Athena, get the data - and maybe do some pre-processing - and then post it to DynamoDB.